# I want to display the following numbers in Loop 1 to 6

Tags: laravel, for-loop, laravel-8

I want to display the following numbers in Loop 1 to 6
like this:
1 - 2

2 - 3

3 - 4

5 - 6

Comment: Is that in a blade view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
$range = range(1, 6);
foreach ($range as $key => $value) {
  if ($key != 0) {
    echo $range[$key - 1].' - '.$range[$key].PHP_EOL;
  }
}
```

```xml
@php($range = range(1, 6))
@foreach ($range as $key => $value)
  @if (!$loop->first())
    <p>{{ $range[$key - 1] }} - {{ $range[$key] }}</p>
  @endif
@endforeach
```